# Criação de txt no construtor da classe, precisa ser fechado posteriormente?

Tags: c#

Quando eu utilizo a classe `StreamWriter` do C# diretamente usando `using`, eu preciso usar o `close`ou o arquivo será fechado assim que sai do escopo do `using`?

```
using (var sw  = new StreamWriter(File.Open(@"c:\arquivo.txt", FileMode.CreateNew))) 
{
    sw.WriteLine("seu texto");          
}
```

Após isso, eu preciso usar o `sw.close();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao utilizar a diretiva `using`, após a escrita/leitura a classe já é liberada, sem necessidade de `.Dispose()` ou `.close()`.

[Diretiva `using`:](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive)

> A palavra-chave using também é usada para criar instruções using, o que ajuda a garantir que objetos [`IDisposable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=net-5.0), tais como arquivos e fontes, sejam tratados corretamente. Para obter mais informações sobre a instrução using, consulte [declaração `using`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).